# If you know the future prices of a stock, what's the best time to buy and sell?

Tags: algorithm, finance

Interview Question by a financial software company for a Programmer position

> Q1) Say you have an array for which the ith element is the price of a given stock on 
>       day i.
>
> If you were only permitted to buy one share of the stock and sell one share 
>       of the stock, design an algorithm to find the best times to buy and sell.

My Solution :
    My solution was to make an array of the differences in stock prices between day i and day i+1 for arraysize-1 days and then use Kadane Algorithm  to return the sum of the largest continuous sub array.I would then buy at the start of the largest continuous array and sell at the end of the largest
continous array.

I am wondering if my solution is correct and are there any better solutions out there???

Upon answering i was asked a follow up question, which i answered exactly the same

> Q2) Given that you know the future closing price of Company x for the next 10 days ,
>       Design a algorithm to to determine if you should BUY,SELL or HOLD for every
>       single day ( You are allowed to only make 1 decision every day ) with the aim of
>       of maximizing profit
>
> Eg: Day 1 closing price :2.24
>          Day 2 closing price :2.11
>           ...
>           Day 10 closing price : 3.00

My Solution: Same as above

I would like to know what if theres any better algorithm out there to maximise profit given
that i can make a decision every single day

Comment: Your idea is the best solution I can think of, but makes me wonder what's the use of knowing the best time to buy a stock, when that time has passed..

Comment: @RezaShirazian well history always repeat itself haha

Comment: @user414076 I thought about it some more, is this correct: BUY if the price goes up tomorrow, then HOLD while the price is going up, then SELL if the price does not go up tomorrow. ?

Comment: What about doing multiple algorithms and comparing revenues and picking the best one. For example trying the algorithm you proposed plus, taking the lowest day and the highest day after that day. Comparing the two algorithms and picking the best one plus any other algorithm you can think of. Kinda like a try everything and go with the best one approach,

Comment: **Prob 1**  could be solved by merely updating the minimal value of prices encountered before position i and check for the difference between element i and that minimal for a maximal difference. Although, both this and your solution run in `O(n)`.

Comment: So did you ask whether they were producing insider trading software? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximizing profit for given stock quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514191/maximizing-profit-for-given-stock-quotes)

Comment: @user2284926: "well history always repeat itself haha" When it comes to stock trading, it doesn't. Software that uses history to determine future price will burn through all your money.

Answer (score 3):

> Q1 If you were only permitted to buy one share of the stock and sell one share of the stock, design an algorithm to find the best times to buy and sell.

In a single pass through the array, determine the index `i` with the lowest price and the index `j` with the highest price. You buy at `i` and sell at `j` (selling before you buy, by borrowing stock, is in general allowed in finance, so it is okay if `j < i`). If all prices are the same you don't do anything.

> Q2 Given that you know the future closing price of Company x for the next 10 days , Design a algorithm to to determine if you should BUY,SELL or HOLD for every single day ( You are allowed to only make 1 decision every day ) with the aim of of maximizing profit

There are only 10 days, and hence there are only `3^10 = 59049` different possibilities. Hence it is perfectly possible to use brute force. I.e., try every possibility and simply select the one which gives the greatest profit. (Even if a more efficient algorithm were found, this would remain a useful way to test the more efficient algorithm.)

Some of the solutions produced by the brute force approach may be invalid, e.g. it might not be possible to own (or owe) more than one share at once. Moreover, do you need to end up owning 0 stocks at the end of the 10 days, or are any positions automatically liquidated at the end of the 10 days? Also, I would want to clarify the assumption that I made in Q1, namely that it is possible to sell before buying to take advantage of falls in stock prices. Finally, there may be trading fees to be taken into consideration, including payments to be made if you borrow a stock in order to sell it before you buy it.

Once these assumptions are clarified it could well be possible to take design a more efficient algorithm. E.g., in the simplest case if you can only own one share and you have to buy before you sell, then you would have a "buy" at the first minimum in the series, a "sell" at the last maximum, and buys and sells at any minima and maxima inbetween.

The more I think about it, the more I think these interview questions are as much about seeing how and whether a candidate clarifies a problem as they are about the solution to the problem.

Comment: You forgot about trading fees. For every deal you perform, you must pay a fee. So if you sell stocks at the same price you bought, you lose money. Also, lowest - highest may not cover the fee.

Comment: @SigTerm You're right, I didn't include that: I'll add it to the answer. Also, under trading fees, if you sell before you buy, you do, I believe, need to pay to borrow the stock.

Comment: " if you sell before you buy, ...need to pay" Of course. If you sell, you pay the fee. If you buy, you also pay the fee. Also, if you simply buy at lowest and sell at highest, that won't maximize the profits, because price can fluctuate back and forth, like a roller coaster (volatile). In this situation there'll be only one highest and one lowest price, but (if you can predict the future) you can make ton of money while price keep moving back and forth. So instead of peaks, you need to detect points when trend turns around, see if that turnaround is profitable, and act accordingly.

Comment: @SigTerm Agreed on all these points. The OP did have some contraints: Q1 states you can only have one buy and one sell, whereas Q2 allows as many buys and sells as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternative answers:

Q1) Work from left to right in the array provided. Keep track of the lowest price seen so far. When you see an element of the array note down the difference between the price there and the lowest price so far, update the lowest price so far, and keep track of the highest difference seen. My answer is to make the amount of profit given at the highest difference by selling then, after having bought at the price of the lowest price seen at that time.

Q2) Treat this as a dynamic programming problem, where the state at any point in time is whether you own a share or not. Work from left to right again. At each point find the highest possible profit, given that own a share at the end of that point in time, and given that you do not own a share at the end of that point in time. You can work this out from the result of the calculations of the previous time step: In one case compare the options of buying a share and subtracting this from the profit given that you did not own at the end of the previous point or holding a share that you did own at the previous point. In the other case compare the options of selling a share to add to the profit given that you owned at the previous time, or staying pat with the profit given that you did not own at the previous time. As is standard with dynamic programming you keep the decisions made at each point in time and recover the correct list of decisions at the end by working backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the prices are the array `P =  [p_1, p_2, ..., p_n]`

Construct a new array `A =  [p_1, p_2 - p_1, p_3 - p_2, ..., p_n - p_{n-1}]`

i.e `A[i] = p_{i+1} - p_i`, taking `p_0 = 0`.

Now go find the [maximum sum sub-array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) in this.

OR

Find a different algorithm, and solve the maximum sub-array problem!

The problems are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to question 1 was correct.

Your answer to question 2 was not correct. To solve this problem you work backwards from the end, choosing the best option at each step. For example, given the sequence { 1, 3, 5, 4, 6 }, since 4 < 6 your last move is to sell. Since 5 > 4, the previous move to that is buy. Since 3 < 5, the move on 5 is sell. Continuing in the same way, the move on 3 is to hold and the move on 1 is to buy.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution for first problem is Correct. Kadane's Algorithm runtime complexity is **O(n)** is a optimal solution for maximum subarray problem. And benefit of using this algorithm is that it is easy to implement.

Your solution for second problem is wrong according to me. What you can do is to store the **left** and **right** index of maximum sum subarray you find. Once you find have maximum sum subarray and its left and right index. You can call this function again on the left part i.e 0 to left -1 and on right part i.e. right + 1 to Array.size - 1. So, this is a **recursion** process basically and you can further design the structure of this recursion with base case to solve this problem. And by following this process you can maximize profit.