# find max possible difference between a[i] and a[j], where 0 < i < a.length and i < j < a.length

Tags: java, arrays, loops

A similar question was posted in [If you know the future prices of a stock, what's the best time to buy and sell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849072/if-you-know-the-future-prices-of-a-stock-whats-the-best-time-to-buy-and-sell/58026902#58026902) but it is not precisely the same.

Given: an array of integers represents a stock price of an item
Problem: find the max possible benefit if we by one share on day X and sell it on day X+n.

I wrote a function that:

1. assumes that maxPossibleBenefit can be made on day 2:

1.1 maxPossibleBenefit = a[1] - a[0]

2. traverses through the array from a[0] to a[a.length -1]:

2.1 If a[X+n] - a[X] > maxPossibleBenefit, then maxPossibleBenefit = a[X+n] - a[X].

3.When X+n == a.length (we reach the end of array), repeat steps 2 and 2.1 starting from a[1], then from a[2], until we reach a.[length-2] to compare last 2 elements.

```
public static int maxBenefit(int[] arr) {

        //first, assuming that max benefit can be received on day 2
        int maxBenefit = arr[1] - arr[0];
        // traverse the entire array and check,
        // will we get more benefit if we buy on day one
        // and sell on day 2, 3, up until the last day in the range:
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            // with every run we shift purchase date by one into the future
            for (int j = i; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
                // if we sell later than on day 2, will we get more benefit?
                if ((arr[j + 1] - arr[j]) > maxBenefit)
                    maxBenefit = arr[j + 1] - arr[j];
            }
        }
        return maxBenefit;
    }
```

But with array {8, 6, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 7, 9, 4}, the function returns 2, while it should be 5 (a[6] - a[2]).

Can you please help me find the flaw in my algorithm?

Comment: Have you tried running it a debugger?

Comment: Actually not, I haven't yet learnt how to use it. Yes, shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use i and j properly, and do not calculate the difference between them.

```
public static int maxBenefit(int[] arr) {

    //first, assuming that max benefit can be received on day 2
    int maxBenefit = arr[1] - arr[0];
    // traverse the entire array and check,
    // will we get more benefit if we buy on day one
    // and sell on day 2, 3, up until the last day in the range:
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {
        // with every run we shift purchase date by one into the future
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; ++j) {
            // if we sell later than on day 2, will we get more benefit?
            int benefit = arr[j] - arr[i];
            if ( benefit > maxBenefit)
                maxBenefit = benefit;
        }
    }
    return maxBenefit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see where the flaw was. Thanks a lot, this solves the problem!