# Stock Profit Maximization: Given Price Array, How to Maximize Profits with Boundaries

Tags: python, optimization

I've been trying to write some code that is based on what has been done with "[Maximizing profit for given stock quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514191/maximizing-profit-for-given-stock-quotes)", but I want to impose certain constraints on what the trader can do. In my code, I have tried to limit the number of stock that he can own to N = 4, and the number of shares that he can buy or sell at a given time interval is C = 1. The goal is to find the set of actions for a given stock price array that maximizes profits at the end.

So for a given price array

```
stock_prices = [20,20,20,20,25,30,25,30,25,20,20,30,35,40,45,50,60,60,50,40,35,30,25,20],
```

optimally, the trader should buy at time intervals 1, 2, 3, and 4 (for $20 each), sell at time intervals 6 and 8 (for $30 each), buy again at 10 and 11, and sell everything at 16, 17, 18, and 19. At the end of the day, the trader should have zero shares of the stock.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
def calcprofit(stock_prices):
    buy=[1]*len(stock_prices) # 1 reflects buy and 0 reflects sell
    profit=0
    m=0
    storage_limit = 4
    c = 1   #Change in shares
    storage = 0
    for i in reversed(range(len(stock_prices))):
        price = stock_prices[i] # shorthand name
        if storage < storage_limit and m <= price:
            buy[i] = 1
            m = price
            storage += c
        if storage >= storage_limit and m >= price:
            buy[i] = 0
            storage -= c
        profit += (m-price)
    return (profit,buy,storage)
```

Currently the code is not able to sell the stock one at a time, or sell or buy an amount determined by the change. Currently, I get this as a result:

```
(505, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 3)
```

Additionally, but not necessary, instead of using a binary system as the link above shows for buying and selling, is it possible to introduce another integer  to show when the trader holds (neither buys nor sells)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dynamic Programming to compute the optimal profit, as follow:

```
stock_prices = [20,20,20,20,25,30,25,30,25,20,20,30,35,40,45,50,60,60,50,40,35,30,25,20]
MAX_STOCKS = 4
memory = {}

def dp(i=0, stockes=0):

  if i == len(stock_prices):
    return 0

  if (i, stockes) in memory:
    return memory[(i, stockes)]

  memory[(i, stockes)] = max(
      dp(i+1, stockes), 
      dp(i+1, stockes+1) - stock_prices[i] if stockes < MAX_STOCKS else -1, 
      dp(i+1, stockes-1) + stock_prices[i] if stockes > 0 else -1)

  return memory[(i, stockes)]


print(dp())
```

Output:

```
160
```

160 match with your described optimal solution. Two important notes about the solution:

1. At each call I compute three possibilities: not buying or selling, buying a stock if limit not reached and selling a stock if we have at least one.
2. In dynamic programming the problem has overlapping structure, where sub-problems appear multiple times, for this reason I use the `memory` dic to memorize recurrent sub-problems.

Comment: Thanks! This works very well. If possible, where would you recommend for a print statement (stating whether the optimal choice is to buy, sell, or hold) to go? I was thinking that if one could identify when the current stocks increased, decreased, or remained constant, one would be able to print the action.

Comment: You are welcome, will I will give you a hint: At each invocation our state is (i=0, stockes=0) and we may follow any of the threes actions (selling, buying, or doing nothing), what we need to know is for a given stock what action we did.

Comment: I have tried implementing this by placing a series of conditional statements that use the status of the number of stocks as premise. When I `print(memory[(i, storage)]` it provides all the `i` values and corresponding stocks at the time interval. To each time interval there are different number of stocks. How do I isolate the ones that the program determined to maximize profit?